# line(records) Count and grep together in a one command on a dat file

Tags: shell, wc

I want to do a line count and get the number into a variable in a shell script.
For eg.

```
 wc -l filename.dat
```

gives `221 filename.dat`
I want to grep '221' into a variable, which I could use later.
Can this be done in a single statement ? I don't want to copy the output of `wc -l` into another file and then grep.

Comment: Word count or line count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the filename to the STDIN of `wc` to get only the number of lines :

```
wc -l <filename.dat
```

To save it as a variable :

```
var="$(wc -l <filename.dat)"
```

Example :

```
$ wc -l foo.txt 
12 foo.txt

$ wc -l <foo.txt 
12

$ var="$(wc -l <foo.txt)"

$ echo "$var"
12
```

Note that as [Stéphane Chazelas has pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228634/linerecords-count-and-grep-together-in-a-one-command-on-a-dat-file/228635#comment389739_228635), some `wc` variants might add spaces before and after the number of lines to get desired alignment.

Comment: Note that some `wc` implementations (typically the traditional ones) insert spaces before and after the number (to right-align on a 8 character column: `␣␣␣␣␣12␣`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, fortunately it didnt add any spaces in my case